# Change footer template in specific CMS page 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, cms, xml, layout-update, ce-1.9.2.2

As the title says I need to change the template path of the footer block for a specific CMS page.
This is what I have in my page.xml:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">


    <default translate="label" module="page">
        <label>All Pages</label>
        <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/1column.phtml">

...

            <block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">
                <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="bottom.container" as="bottomContainer" translate="label">
                    <label>Page Footer</label>
                    <action method="setElementClass"><value>bottom-container</value></action>
                </block>
                <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="newsletter" as="newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml" />
            </block>
```

and this is what I put in the update layout XML box on the specific CMS page on the admin side:

```
<default>
    <reference name="root">
        <reference name="footer">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/html/footer-shop.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
   </reference> 
</default>
```

Footer keeps on showing footer.phtml template instead of footer-shop.phtml.

What is the correct way to change the footer template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the way to do it:

```
<reference name="footer">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/html/footer-shop.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

In your code, you don't need to reference `root`, you only need to reference your `footer` block.

Also you don't need to specify the handle `default` as the CMS module will automatically match your specific CMS page handle with the Layout Update XML.

Comment: I tried your code but I still displays the footer.phtml instead of footer-shop.phtml. The strange thing is that if I activate template hints, the footer is not recognized as separate block.

Comment: @gianis6 didn't notice you were dealing with the CMS update layout XML. See my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to use below code in admin "Layout Update XML".

```
<reference name="footer">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/html/footer-shop.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```